# Custom, user-definable "wildcard" constants in SQL database search -- possible?

Tags: sql, django

My client is making database searches using a django webapp that I've written. The query sends a regex search to the database and outputs the results.

Because the regex searches can be pretty long and unintuitive, the client has asked for certain custom "wildcards" to be created for the regex searches. For example.

`Ω := [^aeiou]` (all non-vowels)

etc.

This could be achieved with a simple permanent string substitution in the query, something like

`query = query.replace("Ω", "[^aeiou]")`

for all the elements in the substitution list. This seems like it should be safe, but I'm not really sure.

He has also asked that it be possible for the user to define custom wildcards for their searches on the fly. So that there would be some other input box where a user could define

`∫ := some other regex`

And to store them you might create a model

```
class RegexWildcard(models.Model):
    symbol = ...
    replacement = ...
```

I'm personally a bit wary of this, because it does not seem to add a whole lot of functionality, but does seem to add a lot of complexity and potential problems to the code. Clients can now write their queries to a db. Can they overwrite each other's symbols?

That I haven't seen this done anywhere before also makes me kind of wary of the idea.

Is this possible? Desirable? A great idea? A terrible idea? Resources and any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're getting paid by the hour....

I don't see how involving the Greek alphabet is to anyone's advantage. If the queries are stored anywhere, everyone approaching the system would have to learn the new syntax to understand them.  Plus, there's the problem of how to type the special symbols.

If the client creates complex regular expressions they'd like to be able to reuse, that's understandable.  Your application could maintain a list of such expressions that the user could add to and choose from.  Notionally, the user would "click on" an expression, and it would be inserted into the query.

The saved expressions could have user-defined names, to make them easier to remember and refer to. And you could define a syntax that referenced them, something otherwise invalid in SQL, such as **::name**.  Before submitting the query to the DBMS, you substitute the regex for the name.
You still have the problem of choosing good names, and training.

To prevent malformed SQL, I imagine you'll want to ensure the regex is valid.  You wouldn't want your system to store a `; drop table CUSTOMERS;` as a "regular expression"!  You'll either have to validate the expression or, if you can, treat the regex *as data* in a parameterized query.

The real question to me, though, is why you're in the vicinity of standardized regex queries.  That need suggests a database design issue: it suggests the column being queried is composed of composite data, and should be represented as multiple columns that can be queried directly, without using regular expressions.

Comment: That last part is really interesting. I want to give that some thought. Thanks. And in fact, I am not getting paid by the hour :-)